# How to make the output type of the comparison block 'double' in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to compare a number to another: if the comparison is true the current value must pass but if not it must stop. But I can't do this idea because the output of the compare block is boolean so if it is true, the output is 1 so the current value will not pass as same number. How can I do this idea? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to use a [Switch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/switch.html) block (under *Commonly Used Blocks* and *Signal Routing*) instead of the Relational Operator block.

There is also a [Data Type Conversion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/datatypeconversion.html) block if you ever do need to convert a Boolean output to double precision, but I don't think that's what you want in this case.